# Can I get root URL to my Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

For example, I have https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/myfunctionname

But I want to have a root link to my function. Something like that:

https://myfunctionname.REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/

How can I get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the URL provided by Cloud Functions, but you can use Firebase Hosting as a proxy to Cloud Functions so you can use a custom domain to access functions deployed to the same project.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to get a different URL from a Cloud Function other than the one automatically generated which will always have the format "https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/hello_get".

If there was a way to do this, it would need to be defined during ht deployment of the function, and according to the [documentation for 'gcloud function deploy'](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy), there is no way to specify a way to change the URL generated.